# Ocultar linha de uma tabela pelo JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria de saber como faço para mostrar e ocultar uma linha inteira de uma tabela no PHP, usando o javascript ou outra função.

Utilizei esta função, porém quando uso a mesma em um `onclick`, a linha ao qual estava oculta aparece inteira sempre na primeira célula da linha anterior.

Função JavaScript

```
function Mostrar(obj) {
    var display = document.getElementById(obj).hidden;
    if(display == true)
        document.getElementById(obj).style.display = 'none';
    else
        document.getElementById(obj).style.display = 'block';
}
```

A tabela ao qual gostaria de ocultar a linha, esta dentro de um `loop for` onde eu tenho a soma de várias despesas de um determinado processo, e a linha que ficará oculta deverá conter as despesas detalhadas deste processo.

Comment: "Java"? Lembre-se que Java e JavaScript são coisas bem diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente faço assim:

```
$("#tabela").on("click",".deletaLinha", function() {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                tr.css("background-color","yellow");
                tr.fadeOut(600, function(){
                    tr.remove();
                });
                return false;
            });
```

Ai na tabela coloco um link assim:

```
<td><a class='deletaLinha' href='#'>Remover</a></td>
```